# Laravel - Migration scripts used multple times across platforms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I just had a thought of serving fresh data for a demo app.

What I want to achieve is to have the schema and a set of data prepared beforehand and got ready to be migrated as the demo app is run. Simply put, every time a user runs the app, the database will be dumped with fresh data.

Is that possible? In Laravel 4, I know when I generate a migration script through the CLI, it seems like it has a timestamps attached to the file name, I was wondering if that would prevent the migration from being executed in later days in the future?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to have the schema and a set of data prepared beforehand and got ready to be migrated as the demo app is run. Simply put, every time a user runs the app, the database will be dumped with fresh data.

Speaking of having a set of prepared data, I think [Database Seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding) is close to what you want.

The docs also mention how you could use the migration and seeding together. Although you'll need to decide how to do the migration + seed yourself. E.g. trigger by artisan command, trigger every page load, etc.

**Rollback all migrations and run them all again ([reference](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)):**

> php artisan migrate:refresh
>
> php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

You could also use packages like [fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to help with generating a closer-to-real-life seed data for you.

---

> In Laravel 4, I know when I generate a migration script through the CLI, it seems like it has a timestamps attached to the file name, I was wondering if that would prevent the migration from being executed in later days in the future?

The timestamp in the migration file name is only used for indicating the order in which the migration should be run. So you don't end up running migrations where you try to add a column before adding its table. As long as you do `php artisan migrate:refresh` and you have set up the `up()` and `down()` in your migration files correctly, it should not be a problem.

Although note that if you are in a team, be sure to check the migration order since two or more members can create migration files in parallel to each other.